# react+express: have my apis directed to `https://api.my_site.com/some_api`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, react-redux

My site is located at `https://my_site.com/` and I want my apis for users located at `https://api.mysite.com/some_api`. How do I do this / what resources can you direct me to? Im using react + redux + express.

Comment: Add ```api.mysite.com``` as a CNAME record in your DNS and then use vhost (https://github.com/expressjs/vhost)

Comment: maybe you wanna use Nginx. [setup docs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)